# how to make a discord bot calculator

Tags: python, discord

so i made some code for a discord bot calculator. it should respond to a command for example calculate 2+2. but well it doesnt work. (im a begginer so the code is probably trash)

```
if "calculate" in message.content or "Calculate" in message.content:
i = message.content.split("alculate ",1)[1]
number = 0
letter = 'd'

for ii in i:
  try:
    number == ii
  except:
    try:
      if letter == "*":
        number*=float(ii) 
        print
      elif letter == "-":
        number -= float(ii)
      elif letter == "+":
        number += float(ii)
      elif letter == "/":
        number/=float(ii)
      if int(ii) != ii:
        ii = letter
    except:
     try:
        if ii == "*":
          ii == letter
        elif ii == "-":
          ii == letter
        elif ii == "+":
          ii == letter
        elif ii == "/":
          ii == letter
     except:
      break
      
await message.channel.send(number)
```

Comment: Use message.content.lower() so you don't have to check if the command starts with a capital or not.
Then it would string recognize "calculate" even if it's spelled "cAlCuLaTe"

Also, you could rename the variable ii to something like current so your code is easier to understand

Comment: The first part isn't indented properly, also do you get an error message, or is the code not working as intended?

Comment: it returns 0 / one of the number you gave it

Comment: i think a better method would be to use a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instead of `discord.Client` which will let you take a string input with the command and then use the `eval()` method